# Cannot use bool delegate(T) as Func<T, bool>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, delegates, func

I have created a delegate type which I use to pass methods around in my code.
I though this would be a good idea because in case I would have to change the signature in future I just have to change it in one single place.

But my problem is now that although having the same signature the delegate seems not to be compatible with a `Func` so for example I cannot use it with LINQ without wrapping it again in a new function which will have performance penalties.

```
public delegate bool IsWalkable(Point point);

return directions.Any(isWalkable); // gives compile error CS1503
```

> Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'IsWalkable' to > 'System.Func<Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Point, bool>'

Am I overlooking something or will it be better to just use `Func<Point, bool>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-8.0#system-linq-enumerable-any-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-boolean)))) requires not just any delegate but specifically `Func<T, bool>`, so you need either use `Func<Point, bool>` for `isWalkable` variable or do something like:

```cs
return directions.Any(isWalkable.Invoke);

// or 

return directions.Any(x => isWalkable(x));
```